# Upper triangular matrix iff transformation applied to vector is in span

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, proof-explanation, solution-verification

Let $B = v_1, . . . , v_n$ be an ordered basis for $V$ and $T : V → V$ be a linear transformation. Prove that $[T]_B$ is upper triangular if and only if $T(v_j ) \in span(v_1, . . . , v_j)$
for all $j = 1, . . . , n$.

My attempt:

Suppose that $[T]_B$ is upper-triangular. Then,

$$[T(v_j)]_B = \begin{pmatrix}
A_{1j}\\
.\\
.\\
.\\
A_{nj}
\end{pmatrix}$$

$$\implies T(v_j) = \sum_{i = 1}^{n} A_{ij}v_i$$

Since $A_{ij} = 0$ for $i>j$, it follows that $T(v_j ) \in span(v_1, . . . , v_j)$.

So, $[T]_B$ is upper-triangular $\implies T(v_j ) \in span(v_1, . . . , v_j)$.

Now, suppose $T(v_j ) \in span(v_1, . . . , v_j)$, then,

$$T(v_j) = c_1v_1 + ... + c_jv_j$$ for scalars $c_1,...,c_n \in F$

[FROM HERE, I HAVE NO IDEA WHAT TO DO]

So, can anyone explain or show what is meant to be done. I can't figure out how the matrix is formed. Also, I'm not sure if the former part of the proof is correct. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Well, the matrix in the basis $B$ is uniquely defined by $T(v_i)$. Try writing that down

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $T(v_j)\in\operatorname{span}\{v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_j\}$, then $T(v_j)$ can be written as $a_{1j}v_1+a_{2j}v_2+\cdots+a_{jj}v_j$. But then$$[T]_B=\begin{bmatrix}a_{11}&a_{12}&a_{13}&\ldots&a_{1n}\\0&a_{22}&a_{23}&\ldots&a_{2n}\\0&0&a_{33}&\ldots&a_{3n}\\\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\0&0&0&\ldots&a_{nn}\end{bmatrix},$$which is an upper triangular matrix.

Comment: How did you construct $[T]_B$? That is, how can you tell that there are $0$s below the diagonal?

Comment: Because the sum $a_{1j}v_1+a_{2j}v_2+\cdots+a_{jj}v_j$ stops at the index $j$, since $T(v_j)$ is a linear combination of $v_1$, $v_2$, \dots, $v_j$.

Comment: Ah ok, that makes sense! Thank you!

Comment: Done. Thanks again!

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos do you mean T(vn) belongs to span(vn) and so on?

Comment: @PrateekMourya No, I don't. I mean what I wrote: for each $j\in\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$, $T(v_j)\in\operatorname{span}\{v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_j\}$.